# Boolean error in equating a mix a values to a integer, all returning false

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I have an array with a mix of values, string and integers, and I have two lists for an x coordinate and a y coordinate to parse into the array which then goes into an if statement to see if it is equal to the integer 5, some of them should be pass but it is returning all fails. This is the code below.

```
for i in range (len(x_co_list)):

    if(array[int(x_co_list[i])][int(y_co_list[i])]=='5'):
        df['PASS_FAIL']='PASS'
        
    else:
        df['PASS_FAIL']='FAIL'
```

I have to add the int() around the list as python gives this error:IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I have also tried printing the array at those indices with this code

```
print(array[int(x_co_list[i])][int(y_co_list[i])])
```

And this prints the correct values of the array.

Thanks

Comment: "an if statement to see if it is equal to the integer 5". Then why is it testing against a string of `'5'`?

Comment: @blhsing Sorry i tried that aswell, ==5 still returns all FAILS when there is supposed to be a PASS